# What are the pros and cons of running PHP as an Apache module or a FastCGI?

Tags: php, apache, vps, plesk

My VPS is giving me the option between running PHP as an Apache Module or a FastCGI.

How should one make this decision? Performance? Security? Ease of use? Compatibility?

I'm using PLESK.

Comment: Is this more appropriate for ServerFault or for StackOverflow?

Comment: Please don't close. If you think it should be transfered do so, but don't close. It's not an open ended question.

Comment: Both the close votes you can see are in fact votes to transfer to webmasters (they appear under the "close" umbrella). It may be quicker for you to delete this question and create a new one over at webmasters. It won't damage your rep if you do so, and if you don't you'll have to either wait for a mod to arrive here or wait for 5 people to vote...

Comment: To anyone else briefly confused by @DaveRandom's comment above, please note that it was posted _before_ this question was migrated here from SO and before it had any answers.

Answer (score 4):

Linking *PHP* as an *Apache HTTPD module* makes them inseparable.

This is not without problems:

Indeed, many *PHP* libraries aren't [threadsafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), **[so it's essential](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)** to use the [*prefork-mpm* module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/prefork.html) for *HTTPD 2.x* in production to implements a non-threaded, pre-forking web server that handles requests in a manner similar to *HTTPD 1.3*.

But this approach strongly affects the performance, which can overload the CPU and RAM, causing timeouts and other troubles.

The manual page [Apache Performance Tuning](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html#compiletime) enlighten us a little more about the advantages and disadvantages:

> The [prefork](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/prefork.html) MPM uses multiple child processes with one thread each. Each process handles one connection at a time. On many systems, prefork is comparable in speed to worker, but it uses more memory. Prefork's threadless design has advantages over worker in some situations: it can be used with non-thread-safe third-party modules, and it is easier to debug on platforms with poor thread debugging support.

So, IMHO, *PHP* with *FastCGI* is more suitable in production.

Moreover, my preference is for *[mod_fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/25)* rather than *[mod_fcgid](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html)* because it provides more functionalities, such as the ability to define an external process manager.

Anyway, there will be no more needs for the *prefork-mpm* module, and it will finally be possible to pass on the [*worker-mpm* module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html), much more effective; except that the management process is handled through a shell script to launch the *php-cgi* executable, which isn't very convenient.

Fortunately, we can use the [*FastCGI* Process Manager for *PHP* (*PHP-FPM*)](http://php-fpm.org/), a popular patch [natively integrated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php) since *PHP 5.3.3*. Unfortunately, if you are using *PHP 5.2.x*, you'll be confined to the classical *FastCGI*.

Still, **it's vital to be aware of the possible vulnerabilities involved by the CGI mode**, as reported on the manual page [CGI and command line setups](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php):

> **Warning**
>   A server deployed in CGI mode is open to several possible vulnerabilities. Please read our [CGI security section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.php) to learn how to defend yourself from such attacks.

You can take a look at this blog post, which contains an example of practical use, and which was of great help in writing this response:

[php, fastcgi, fpm et apache (French)](http://www.lolart.net/blog/ez-publish/php-fastcgi-fpm-et-apache)
[php, fastcgi, and apache fpm (English with Google Translate)](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.lolart.net/blog/ez-publish/php-fastcgi-fpm-et-apache&act=url)

Answer (score 0):

No. It is actually a bit more complicated then that. As far as I understood the question, when Apache is treating a request it loads all the PHP library (in case of PHP as Apache Module). Even when executing a static ressource request. So it consumes a lot of memory.

The other solution is a light weighted front httpserver. It will executes static request and forward php request to the PHP-CGI.

To resume this :

- Apache PHP Module : Simple, easy, standard, to be used in 90%.
- PHP-CGI : Performant when there are a lot of static ressources (images, pictures, etc). A bit more complicated to configure, maintain.

Answer (score -1):

PHP with FAST CGI option runs as fast as it runs on LINUX OS. Microsoft has made lots of improvement in IIS7 for PHP to cover OPEN SOURCE SCRIPT (WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, etc...) hosting market.

I am hosting my PHP applications on IIS7 with FastCGI and running WordPress as smoothly as it runs on Linux Hosting. I just need to upload my php files into the public_html directory to run my php applications.